# Script for a community blog

Tags: looking-for-a-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I want to start a community blog: a blog where anyone can post. Basically: I need a CMS that has the following features:

- People can post from the front end: they don't have to go to an administrative interface.
- Anyone can post
- The popular posts (the ones with the most views, links, comments, etc.) are moved up to the home page, while the less popular posts are not as visable.
- Categories and Tags
- Comments
- Some sort of internal trackback system: if user1 creates a post with a link to user2's post, then user1's post should show up in the comments of user2's post.
- a simple profile (name, avatar, bio, etc.)
- The ability to rate post's and comments.
- Some sort of anti-spam system.

Technology: php

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question invites subjective answers so I am marking it as a Community Wiki post. You may want to add details on technologies (Windows/ASP.NET/LAMP/?) you use or plan to use to help narrow down suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Pligg](http://pligg.com/) if you get the chance.  From their site:

> Pligg started as a simple CMS to let
>   users submit and vote on news
>   articles, and that's still what we do
>   best. Vote on stories that interest
>   you and articles that receive enough
>   votes will appear on the homepage of
>   your Pligg site. Pligg offers a 5 star
>   method for voting or the more
>   traditional numbered voting as seen on
>   sites like Digg, Mixx, or Reddit.